# How to apply physics on instances of group?

Tags: physics, groups, instances

I have a group of multiple objects. I make a couple of instances via `Shift + A` and shift them along `Z`. Then I try to drop them using game engine and I have `Record Animation` turned on. While in play mode, everything looks like it should. But when I stop it and move animation crusor, for some reason only one instance is at its position, others are shifted. E.g. if I shift them 60 units upwards from original group before playmode, then all instances except one are 120 units upper than original group after I quit playmode. How do I do it correctly?

Comment: you don't need to use the BGE to get a rigid body sim, that is build right in to blender.

Comment: Thank you. But problem is still there. Maybe it just isn't allowed to use instances for that...